# What are the default font characteristics in Android ?

Tags: android, fonts, default

I know that fonts properties can be found in the `TypeFace` class but I can't find the default characteristics of the writing in Android. I mean, if I take a `TextView` and simply do `setText("Blabla")` on it, what will I get? Which size in px? Which font? etc.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can check the default style of the widgets here: [android/res/values/styles.xml](https://raw.github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml)

Then, looking for Textview you reach

```
  <style name="Widget.TextView">    
     <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>    
 </style>
```

and after researching a little bit, you find out that this appearance is defined in the same styles.xml file

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Small">    
 <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>    
 <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>    
 <item name="android:textColor">?textColorSecondary</item>    
</style>
```

where

```
<item name="textColorSecondary">@android:color/secondary_text_dark</item>
```

these colors are defined in [/res/color/](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/color), check [/res/color/secondary_text_dark.xml](https://raw.github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/master/core/res/res/color/secondary_text_dark.xml)

Bookmarking the [android/res/values](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/values) folder is a must!

Update: my old links are broken, check [Android core resources folder](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res) on Github. Thanks to kreker for the link.

Comment: While the system styles do have semantic meaning, you shouldn't rely on the values being the same from platform version to platform version, or from device to device. It is still a very useful bookmark to have though. :)

Comment: great I knew of these pages of course but they slipped my mind when I asked my question. Thx for the reminder !

Comment: where did you found that <item name="textColorSecondary">@android:color/secondary_text_dark</item> ?

Comment: looks like the source code isn't accessible any more through web, you'll have to download the kernel and browse through it. Check any of the links in my answer for instructions on how to download Android's source code.

Comment: what about this https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res ?

Answer (score 10):

For the newer 4.0 ICS etc there's the Android design pages which shows a list of font sizes:

http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html

All specified as 'sp' units

HTH