# What is the default text size on Android?

Tags: android, text-size

I have a mixture of Buttons and an own View, where I set my text size using Paint.setTextSize(). I want the text size to look the same like the text on the Button. Now, I can of course set the text size of the button to e.g. 18sp, and use 18 in my view. But for a better integration, I simply would like to know, what text size is "normal" for buttons. From my test, it should be something like 12sp, but I have not found any documentation on this.

Leaving the default sizes leaves way too small text on the view.

Maybe I should use still another approach to this issue?

Comment: Well, seems it is unkown. So I choose 16sp. This looks good enough, while not being too small (I need glasses already or a HTC HD :-) By the way, to scale the font for the graphics you need to find the scaling factor for your device first with float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; Multiply this with your desired text size in sp, and set the size with Paint.setTextSize.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the default font caracteristics in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285225/what-are-the-default-font-caracteristics-in-android)

Comment: Searching the web for `abc_text_size_medium_material` (one of the standard size dimensions) gives the [Material dimensions XML file from App Compat](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/dimens_material.xml) which contains all the standard sizes.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This will return default size of text on button in pixels.

### Kotlin

```
val size = Button(this).textSize
```

### Java

```
float size = new Button(this).getTextSize();
```

Answer (score 221):

### In general:

Three "default" textSize values:

```
 - 14sp
 - 18sp
 - 22sp
```

These values are defined within the following TextAppearances:

```
 - TextAppearance.Small
 - TextAppearance.Medium
 - TextAppearance.Large
```

More information about Typography can be found in the [design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html)

### Related to your question:

If you don't set a custom textSize or textAppearance, **TextAppearance.Small** will be used.

---

### Update: Material design:

New [guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-standard-styles) related to font and typefaces. The standard rule of 14sp remains (body).

**Examples how to set textappearances**

AppCompat version:

> android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body"

Lollipop and up version:

> android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Body"

Comment: Would like to add to the above list, `12sp` for `Micro`

Comment: On the other hand, `TextApperance.Micro` is actually non-existent. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301329/missed-textappearances-micro-appearance)

Comment: Interestingly, even in the Material theme the small/medium/large sizes are still 14/18/22 even though 18 and 22 aren't standard sizes as per the Material typography guide. Presumably this is for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 62):

Looks like someone else found it: [What are the default font characteristics in Android ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285225/what-are-the-default-font-caracteristics-in-android/4285644#4285644)

There someone discovered the default text size, for TextViews (which use TextAppearance.Small) it's 14sp.

Answer (score 19):

Default values in appcompat-v7

```
<dimen name="abc_text_size_body_1_material">14sp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_text_size_body_2_material">14sp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_text_size_button_material">14sp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_text_size_caption_material">12sp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_text_size_display_1_material">34sp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_text_size_display_2_material">45sp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_text_size_display_3_material">56sp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_text_size_display_4_material">112sp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_text_size_headline_material">24sp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_text_size_large_material">22sp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_text_size_medium_material">18sp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_text_size_menu_material">16sp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_text_size_small_material">14sp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_text_size_subhead_material">16sp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_text_size_subtitle_material_toolbar">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_text_size_title_material">20sp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar">20dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 5):

http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/

```
Text size

Type    Dimension
Micro   12 sp
Small   14 sp
Medium  18 sp
Large   22 sp
```

Answer (score 5):

You can find standard sizes for everything in Google's [style guide.](https://material.io/guidelines/style/typography.html)

Here are the values they use for for buttons:

Buttons

English: Medium 14sp, all caps

Dense: Medium 15sp, all caps

Tall: Bold 15sp

Answer (score 3):

## the default text size of the textview

if you not used any of the below

TextAppearance.Small

TextAppearance.Medium

TextAppearance.Large

then the default size is 14sp

Answer (score 2):

Default text  size vary from device to devices

Type    Dimension
Micro   12 sp
Small   14 sp
Medium  18 sp
Large   22 sp

Answer (score 0):

The default size that appears when you delete the font size while developing an application in Android studio in December 2022 is 14sp.

Having SP is good for compatibility by device.
On the other hand, it is an advantage that the font is 14, that is, small, because it does not have a problem of fitting on small devices with large fonts.