# Missing TextAppearances.Micro style

Tags: android, android-styles, android-textattributes

According to [Android Developer Design Style for Typography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html), there are 4 `TextAppearance`s (Micro, Small, Medium, Large).

But there is no predefined style for Micro:

```
?android:attr/textAppearanceMicro
android:style/TextAppearance.Micro
```

None of them can be found in sources of Android. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question! After researching a little bit, I didn't find any results for "TextAppearance.Micro".

On the other hand, I found the [official Android source for style resource](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) related to `TextAppearance`s.

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?textColorSecondary</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
</style>
```

As you can see, all of them only affect the text size (except `TextAppearance.Small`, which also affect the text color). So, I can safely say that the site displays the text sizes as a guideline only. On the other hand, you can always add a custom style to support `TextAppearance.Micro`! Just insert this inside `styles.xml`.

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Micro" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

and use it like:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Micro" />
```

---

On a bit related note, when I searched "textAppearanceMicro", I found 3 projects on GitHub. All of them adding some custom attributes, which one of them is `textAppearanceMicro`. Also, all of them are using `ActionBarSherlock`. I don't know whether there is a connection between `textAppearanceMicro` and `ActionBarSherlock`, but I didn't find that attribute was used anywhere in the code.

Comment: Thanks, now I am using custom style as you suggested. I'm just trying to follow Android guidelines which recommends to use only these four appearanves. So the first option was to use the framework :) Seems like this appearance is rarely used.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use the Google `AppCompat` Library, you can use the following:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption" />
```