# Why i have in TextView margin?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I make simple xml file for android view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/recipe_step_number_textView"
        android:text="STEP #NUM"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:id="@+id/recipe_step_title_editText"
        android:hint="add step title"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

He, how you see, have very simple TextView and EditText, but TextView have a margin a few pixels in Top, looks like this:

[image: Screen from Studio]

why i have margin top?

**UPD** Thank you very much! As I found out there are many ways to solve such trivial issues and almost all they fit

Comment: this margin become from gravity because you are using android:gravity="centre" so all text of textview shift in centre of textview so you see the margin in top of text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the default size of textview define [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22405306/6097062) your are using wrap_content for it's height.. 
That's why it is showing something different as your edit text (Different margins)..
Either you have to give the **text size** for it...or you can change **textview's height** to `match_parent`.

Comment: thx @Saurabh! Your answer helpful for me. I make a textview's height to match_parent, but solution with layout_gravity="center" it seemed to me more versatile. And thx for your link, it is useful for my learning.

Comment: Mine pleasure dear... you can also remain gravity attribute to it..Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Try like This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recipe_step_number_textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="STEP #NUM" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/recipe_step_title_editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:hint="add step title" />
```

Comment: Thx for answer! I did like you advised. but i make this: android:layout_gravity="center"

Answer (score 1):

You give `android:gravity="center"` and give `android:layout_weight="1"` , here your text is large and in center. So, its looks like that.

Its better if you use `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_step_number_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="STEP #NUM" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/recipe_step_title_editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/recipe_step_number_textView"
        android:hint="add step title" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_step_number_textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="STEP #NUM" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/recipe_step_title_editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:hint="add step title" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Add `weightSum` to your `Root Layout`.

**Refer this.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_step_number_textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="STEP #NUM" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/recipe_step_title_editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:hint="add step title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT 1 :**

> Add this line to your `Text View` if you don't want to give `weightSum` is the only Solution.

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

**Or**

**EDIT 2:**

> Set specific size of `Text View` using.

```
android:textSize="12sp"
```

Comment: Does not make any sense!

Comment: @NiravRanpara Check the output of this. No need for Downvote at all. Not showing margin at all.

Comment: thx for answer @jaydroider, but this is not solution for my problem (i make how you say, but as I understand the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum) this parameter is not mandatory)

Comment: @mamba0767 Check my edited answer is the only solution for you.

Comment: @jaydroider: I did not downvoted! and you dont have to right to say about anything !

Comment: @NiravRanpara The matter here is not about right to say anything!!!!!. Don't take it as negative.

Comment: @jaydroider: Dear if you dont know who downvoted then why are you blame me !

Comment: @jaydroider: If somebody think that u r ans is not good enough then they do

Comment: @NiravRanpara I don't have a problem with that. i will improve my answer for that at the end.

Comment: @mamba0767 Have you checked my **EDIT 1** and **EDIT 2** part and let me know !!!

Comment: @mamba0767 have you applied my changes let me know ?

Comment: @mamba0767 Appreciate my answer with up-vote if it;s helpful to you.

Comment: @jaydroider helped me another way, but about android:singleLine="true" I didn't know, thank you