# what is the default font size for most mobiles?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

We already know the default font size in most web browsers is 16 pixels, but what about mobile phones? Does it have a default web font size?
I'm asking because I'm willing to make a mobile-friendly website and I wish to know what is going to happen if I set the size of *sth* to **2em** for example, how many pixels would that be?
note: I don't use JQuery or any type of frameworks.

Comment: You should try to understand how, and why, you should use *em* (or any other type of dynamic sizing). It doesn't matter what the "default" size is, you're constructing something that should work regardless. Given that you don't have any control over what IS the default size (given that users can adjust this as they please), why do you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

[this question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611411/what-is-the-default-text-size-on-android)

**For android:**
currently there are three default sizes as stated by [Tobrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22405306/8040906)

**For IOS:** there is a range for different applications which can be found in the [human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/typography/)