# Default text size setting for Android?

Tags: android

Is there a standard, default text size (100% zoom) for Android that I can depend upon for consistency? I'm referring to the **OS Settings** value, ie

[image]

I'm trying to configure a "base" text size (in ***sp***), and wasn't sure if it
should be relative to the middle setting or the minimum and/or maximum (tiny/huge) setting(s)?

My particular device has the following screen specs:

```
WidthPixels  = 2048
HeightPixels = 1536
DensityDpi   = Xhigh
Density      = 2
Xdpi         = 265.404
Ydpi         = 264.056
```

Comment: **Tobrun**'s answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611411/what-is-the-default-text-size-on-android

Comment: https://material.io/guidelines/style/typography.html#typography-standard-styles

Comment: Design for medium, and if people want to scale to a bigger or smaller let them (by using sp everywhere for text).

Comment: @GabeSechan Alright thanks... Does center position correspond to 100% (I guess I could determine this without much difficulty)?

Comment: I would assume so.  My UI for that looks a bit different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[14sp is the default](https://material.io/guidelines/style/typography.html), for phones and tablets at least.

Comment: There appears to be different values for the **app bar**, **buttons**, **sub heading**, and **body**. So for the **text size** slider, is there a default "position" (which apparently corresponds to this set of quantities)?

Comment: Only a percentage: 100%, which would be the default sp for the specific entities. Slide it to 120% and you can increase the sp on all the entities by 20%. The body size would become 17 sp (rounded), the title size X sp. etc.