# Android: How to get the default app style?

Tags: android, textview, android-button, android-styles

I'm trying to find a way to get the default styles, but seems I cannot find a way to do that. So my question will be is there a way to get all the styles for the app(stuff like, the default text size, default text color, button background color, etc..).. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the default text size on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611411/what-is-the-default-text-size-on-android)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set everything in styles.xml

For example:

```
 <style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/khand_medium</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateHidden</item>
    <item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_32dp</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/CustomDialogStyle</item>

    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/ts_black</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/ts_black</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_dark_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary_dark_color</item>

    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_color</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary_dark_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/blue</item>

    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/MyDarkToolbarStyle</item>
</style>
```