# How to get TextView style form it's xml?

Tags: android

I extends the TextView, but I can't get the TextView's textsize.

```
android:textSize="23sp"
```

I know `getTextSize()` in the java code can get It, but I still had the value when user didn't set the attribute （means not have `android:textSize=...`）.

So I can't use the `getTextSize()` method.

so, how can I get the framework's style value form it's `AttributeSet` ？

———————————— append ——————————————

when I have two TextView in the xml like this:

```
<TextView
   android:height ..
   android:width ..
   android:textSize="16sp"
/>

<TextView
   android:height ..
   android:width ..
/>
```

I want to get their textsize value in java code like this:
(16),(0)

I know textView has the `getTextSize()` method.
But the method will provider me two value （16）,（16）。because the second value from the TextView‘s default，I don't want the default ，I just want the message about my user did't set the textSize in the xml！

I hope I have explained it clearly enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the default text size on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611411/what-is-the-default-text-size-on-android)

Comment: @MahmoudOmara thanks , I have edit my question my clearly

Answer (score 0):

You can get like :

Kotlin

```
val size = Textview(this).textSize
```

Java

```
float size = new Textview(this).getTextSize();
```

Comment: thanks, I know the method, but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I think when you take UI widgets/object from xml then it is statically inflating in your class. Till now user does not have any roll.

> user didn't set the attribute

To answer this

1. Create TextView object programmatically
2. Have a simple interface to notify.
3. Change textView.setTextSize() and
4. Call interface method to notify user about change in textview.

So in this way you will sure get information whether user have set textSize or not.