# Android ListView font size and typeface

Tags: android, listview, text-size

I have a `ListView` and a couple of `TextViews` in my activity. I noticed that the `ListView` has a very neat font size and text by default. How can I get the text size and typeface of the `ListView` and apply to the `TextView`?

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: I am using the SherlockLight theme in my activity, but have not set any theme in my ListView. The TextView font seems larger then needed and is slightly ugly, but the LsitView font is the right size, although that to contains TextViews.

Answer (score 2):

The default size for TextView is 14sp. You can look it up  [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4285644/1661054)

You can change the font size of your textview in your XML layout.
As of your ListView, are you using a custom adapter for it? What type of Adapter?

You can check this tutorial to learn more about custom adapters: [Customizing Android ListView Items with Custom ArrayAdapter](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)

It would be helpful if you can add code.